# django-template: read database response text as HTML

Tags: javascript, python, html, django

- I am collecting user input and storing them in database with html tags to retain the formatting.
- for example: an response coming from database could be

> `asdsad <br/>- 12321312<br/>- 332423<br/>* e23ee<br/>$ dweqw`

- Usually I care only about line breaks
- While reading this response from django-template, I do

> ```
>  <div id="right_suggest_div" name={{ suggestion.key }}>   
>    {{ suggestion.text }}  
>    <p class="padding">Votes: {{ suggestion.votes }} </p>
>  </div>
> ```

**Question:** 
- Is it possible to render `suggestion.text` as html?

Comment: What do you mean by "As HTML"? I guess you want it unescaped, right? If so, you can use the |safe template filter.

Comment: @jcollado, I replaced \n with <br/> tags to save in app-engine model and return the text to front-end, but don't know how to render that as HTML. I did <p>{{ suggestion.text }}</p> but it didn't work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default Django will replace symbols like ">" and "<" with HTML entities.
I imagine that making it skip escaping the HTML would remedy the situation.

```
{% autoescape off %}
<div id="right_suggest_div" name={{ suggestion.key }}>   
   {{ suggestion.text }}  
   <p class="padding">Votes: {{ suggestion.votes }} </p>
 </div>

{% endautoescape %}
```

or use the `safe` filter `{{ suggestion.text|safe }}`

Answer (score 3):

This is what [safe](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#safe) is for.

```
<div id="right_suggest_div" name={{ suggestion.key }}>   
  {{ suggestion.text|safe }}  
  <p class="padding">Votes: {{ suggestion.votes }} </p>
</div>
```

But, please think about the situation that a user enters

```
<script>//do so nasty stuff</script>
```

as their input. You'll basically be serving that content to your users.